# How to test all links on a page with Selemiun IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm new at using Selenium and I'm surprised this question hasn't been asked before but, does anymore know how I can check all the links on a page to make sure none of them are broken?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check all the links on a page using selenium if so the first you need to click and you need to record first. And you can check with `assertLocation`. It was broken or not.But I want to give you some advice if you have many tests if so please use webdriver. Because IDE have many limitation.

You can check this article for webdriver [Finding the broken links in a webpage using Selenium](http://veera-myseleniumblog.blogspot.com/2012/01/finding-broken-links-in-webpage-using.html)

Comment: Yeah I can saw this post but, it seems to be a tutorial for Selenium WebDriver not the IDE. I'm still amazed that there ins't more documentation of the IDE.

Comment: You seem to be right. The IDE is has too many limitations so I'm going to install the WebDriver and try what you suggested above.

Comment: As for me I am using Selenium Webdriver! You can see more details at Selenium Webdriver [documencation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/)

Answer (score -1):

First you need to fetch all the links.

```
public static void allLinks(WebDriver driver)
    {

    List<WebElement> links =driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    for(int i =0;i<links.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.println(links.get(i).getText()); 

    }

    }
```

Here I am just printing all the hyper links by using tag name as all hyperlinks have this anchor tag `<a>`.

Hope this helps.